# Unidirectional current and bi-directional voltage device

Tags: voltage, current

Which is that device which can take in current in one direction irrespective of the voltage polarity across it? ( We can rule solid state switches - diode, SCRs etc).

Comment: Sounds like an inductor. Could you be more specific and provide some example scenario?

Comment: Its not an inductor as it has no directional restrictions as far as current flow is concerned. The direction of current in the inductor can be changed. Think of it as a battery which cannot source but can only sink current. It's hard to articulate with examples and scenarios. Will do when I think of something.

Comment: Think you're talking about a rectifier? It's not a single component, but 4 diodes arranged in a specific way.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're talking about an "ideal current source", which is more of a theoretical construct, rarely found in physical circuits. Most current sources used in practice can't tolerate a reversal in voltage; they're designed to either supply power to the circuit or absorb power from the circuit, but not both.

But an ideal source must do both, functioning as either a power source or a power sink, depending on the polarity of the voltage. If the current arrow points to the positive terminal, then it's supplying power to the circuit. If the arrow points to the negative terminal, then it's absorbing power from the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

> Which is that device

It's an imaginery device because to...

> take in current in one direction irrespective of the voltage polarity

... implies it has positive conduction when the voltage polarity is in one direction but has negative conduction when the voltage polarity is in the opposite direction.

If, however, you mean that it conducts in one direction only, maybe you are thinking of a diode?

Answer (score 0):

Current is not an entity by itself but a resultant of applied potential.
Hence in your hypothetical device, where current flows in same direction regardless of polarity is not possible.
In case of one polarity (say positive polarity), The device conducts in said direction.

In case of the 2nd polarity or polarity reversal (say negative polarity), the device either conducts in reverse direction (regardless of magnitude) or does not conduct at all. Either ways it cannot continue to conduct in the same direction as it was in case of polarity 1.

As cited earlier, a combination of the devices can be used to create an apparent flow like in a full bridge rectifier. Even in that case it is not one device but 2 sets of path of devices, where the devices in action are always in forward bias during conduction. (during reversal of polarity the path does not conduct.)